# C2DM always indicates "Unauthorized" for python code

Tags: android, python, android-c2dm

I tried to use python to write the app server side code to send message to device. I think I could get authorization token successfully, but when I use it to send message, it always shows **"HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"**. My code is here:

```
import urllib, urllib2

class ClientLoginTokenFactory:
_token = None

def __init__(self):
    self.url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
    self.accountType = 'HOSTED_OR_GOOOGLE'
    self.email = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
    self.pwd = 'xxxxx'
    self.service = 'ac2dm'
    self.source = 'com.lei.c2dmtest'

def getToken(self):
    if self._token is None:
        values = {'accountType':self.accountType,'Email':self.email,'Passwd':self.pwd,'source':self.source,'service':self.service}
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        request = urllib2.Request(self.url,data)
        response =  urllib2.urlopen(request)
        responseAsString = response.read()
        #print responseAsString
        responseAsList = responseAsString.split('\n')
        self._token = responseAsList[2].split('=')[1]
        print self._token

    return self._token

class C2DM:
def __init__(self):
    self.url = 'https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send'
    self.clientAuth = None
    self.registrationId = None  
    self.collapseKey = None
    self.data = {}

def sendMessage(self):
    if self.registrationId == None or self.collapseKey == None:
        return False
    clientAuthFactory = ClientLoginTokenFactory()
    self.clientAuth = clientAuthFactory.getToken()
    print self.clientAuth
    values = {'registration_id': self.registrationId, 'collapse_key': self.collapseKey, 'data.msg': 'Hello!!!'}
    #print values
    headers = {'Authorization': 'GoolgeLogin auth=' + self.clientAuth}
    #print headers
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    request = urllib2.Request(self.url, data, headers)

    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        responseAsString = response.read()
        return "AAA"
        return responseAsString
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print 'HTTPError ' + str(e)

sender = C2DM()
sender.registrationId = 'APA91bGZaTpEgJ9a4tOgFTisedsJCOBFvsdwSkKqfzY97QyOiDlzvlZJv6cP1xDENw6DJM3sYTLslGGke0yAMTH9Ep0eeDmfVLUuM2bkFfwKWGyLG4HQDHR1zxw5TN1hoagi5FLWXYKmEQAvX6Qw-rIiwg03UBrvXA'
sender.collapseKey = 3
response = sender.sendMessage()
```

the **registrationId** is also correct, which I have using java code test and prove it works. But when I convert it to python, it always indicates "Unauthorized"

Anybody has any ideas about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped `GoogleLogin`, you have written `GoolgeLogin`.